# How to get user detail from on client list page (index.ctp). client table contain added_by column which is user id in cake php 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

```
<?php 
  foreach ($clients as $client){
    // pr($client->branches);die;
    // $employee->user->role->name;
?>
<tr class="gradeX">
  <td><?php echo $client->id;// $employee->has('user') ? $this->Html->link($employee->user->name, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $employee->user->id]) : '' ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $client->name; ?></td>
  <td>
    <?php 
      echo $client->has('branches') ? $this->Html->link(count($client->branches),['controller' => 'branches', 'action' => 'index',$client->id],['style' => 'color:#f07c3b ']) : "0"; 
    ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php 
      echo $client->added_by;
    ?>
   </td>
   <td>
     <?php 
       echo $this->Html->link('<i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit"></i> ', ['controller' => 'clients', 'action' => 'edit', $client->id],['escape' => false]); 
       echo $this->Form->postLink('<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" title="Archive"></i>', ['action' => 'delete', $client->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete'),'escape' => false]);
     ?>
    </td>                                   
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Some indentation, please.

Comment: did you use association!

Comment: If the table actually contains an "added_by" field, and it's set as an association, you'll run into problems. The column should be "added_by_id", and then "added_by" will be the entity with that user's record.